# How to use alpha channels with Blender internal 16.04 64 bit

Tags: blender

I'm trying to do a Dragonfly but I can't find how to do this, here's an answer at [blender Stack](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30394/how-to-use-transparent-texture-in-the-glsl-shading-mode-in-bge)

Here are my settings and a render. My main idea is that the Alpha channel would be solid in white and transparent in black.

[image: Settings]

[image: Render view]

Comment: 127 questions on Ask Ubuntu have the blender tag like this question does, so this question is also not off topic.

Comment: It's not strictly off-topic, but surely you're much likely to get answers over at [blender.se]? I doubt many people here have the expertise to advise.

Comment: @Zanna I checked the tags before posting the question.

Comment: @karel seems like most of them are about installing and running blender, not doing complex operations in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved by making  a new **PNG** file with the background colors and transparent pixels in the save dialog and using `Z-transparency` along with the image as a Texture

[image: Gimp save]

[image: Z-Transparency]

[image: Final result]